# 301 redirect vs parking

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, dns, parking

I have several domain names registered, each a slight variant of each other.

E.g,

fastcar.com
fast-car.com
fastcar.co.uk
fast-car.co.uk

etc..

I don't wish to be penalized for duplicate content or spammy links by any of the major search engines.

Should I park them all directly on the main domain I wish to promote, 301 redirect them to the main domain or not use them at all?

If 301 redirects are the best option, would having two web hosting accounts be better than one?

Example:

Hosting account 1 has fastcar.com linked through the dns.

Hosting account 2 has fast-car.com, fastcar.co.uk, fast-car.co.uk linked through dns, and 301 redirects pointing to fastcar.com

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd 301 redirect and then specify your preferred URL:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: A few weeks ago Google announced they will start support for cross domain canonical tags.  But I would advice at the moment to use 301's.